# Why is my formatter in the controller not working?

Tags: sapui5

I've defined a new custom module:

status-app/formatter.js

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        stringToInt: function(value) {
            console.log("Called: " + value);
            return parseInt(value);
        }
    }
});
```

Then in my controller I defined it as dependency like in [Step 23](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html) of the walkthrough and added as controller property.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "status-app/formatter"
], function (Controller, formatter) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("stibam-status.Main", {

        //formatter: formatter, 

        formatter: {
            stringToInt: function(value) {
                console.log(value);
                return "";
            }
        },

    [...]
});
```

I've tried both variants of the code but the formatter is not called. I printed in my onInit-function `this.formatter` but it was set correctly. Why is my view not calling my formatter only if I use a anonymous function in the view itself?

Not working

```js
oColListItem.addCell((new sap.m.Text()).bindText({ 
    path: "statusData>AnzPdf", 
    formatter: ".formatter.stringToInt"
}));
```

Working

```js
oColListItem.addCell((new sap.m.Text()).bindText({ 
    path: "statusData>AnzPdf", 
    formatter: function(value) {
        console.log(value); 
        return parseInt(value);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The bindinginfo you provide to the `bindText()` method [expects a function](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindProperty) for its property `formatter`. It should look like this:

When inside the `Controller`:

```js
oColListItem.addCell((new sap.m.Text()).bindText({ 
    path: "statusData>AnzPdf", 
    formatter: this.formatter.stringToInt
}));
```

When inside a `JSView`:

```js
createContent: function(oController){
    //...
    oColListItem.addCell((new sap.m.Text()).bindText({ 
        path: "statusData>AnzPdf", 
        formatter: oController.formatter.stringToInt
    }));
    //...
}
```

The walkthrough you referenced uses [XMLViews](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView.html). In a XMLView the binding info is parsed from the attribute value (a plain string) by the [XMLTemplateProcessor](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/XMLTemplateProcessor.js#L15). It resolves values like ".formatter" on the `Controller` of the `View`.

When you're using a `JSView` or creating `Control`s in your `Controller` then you supply the BindingInfo object directly. No string-parsing involved.

Comment: Okay, thank you, but now I get the error that `this.formatter` is undefined. This seems to be my current element (text-element) and not the controller.

Comment: Added a second example for code inside `JSView.createContent()`. When inside the `Controller` perhaps you have to save your this? `var that = this; /* ... somewhere in a callback function */ formatter: that.formatter.stringToInt`

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, please post more code, especially in which context you are creating the Controls.

Comment: @Gerrit Any response? Otherwise, I'd suggest to accept this answer to help other readers to find a good solution

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue with this code.

```
return Controller.extend("convanl.ConvAnualDesemp.controller.View1", {
formatter: formatter,

----------------------------
    var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                        cells: [
                               new sap.m.Text().bindText({
                               path: "Rut", 
                               formatter: that.formatter.entregaRutFormateado}),
                               new sap.m.Text({
                                text: "{DescEstado}"
                            })]});
```

Comment: Please avoid putting code without explaining why it solves the problem. For the question author, the code itself might not be self-explanatory. Besides that, the suggested solution was already proposed by the existing answer. Try to upvote or adding more values to it by suggesting edits.